# Setting up Domain on DigitalOcean to Django & Nginx

Tags: django, nginx, digital-ocean

Finishing up site migration, I've been able to get it running on the droplet [IP](http://162.243.173.84/) I've also checked if [IP propagation](https://viewdns.info/propagation/?domain=safariguides.org) is complete

[image]

and I've added the domain to digitalocean

[image]

When I try the domain I get `This site can’t be reached`. I've tried to set up the nginx file to match this

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name http://safariguides.org 162.243.173.84 safariguides.org;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/sammy/webapps/kpsga;
    }
    location /media/ {
        root /home/sammy/webapps/kpsga;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

and in the settings file

```
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    'http://safariguides.org',
    'http://162.243.173.84/',
    '*'
]
```

finally adding the `*` for maximum matches.

checking for errors in nginx logs shows this

```
sammy@kpsga:~/webapps/kpsga/kpsga$ sudo tail -F /var/log/nginx/error.log
2020/11/03 06:55:50 [warn] 70740#70740: server name "http://safariguides.org" has suspicious symbols in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/kpsga:3
2020/11/03 07:00:36 [alert] 70778#70778: *14 open socket #16 left in connection 9
2020/11/03 07:00:36 [alert] 70778#70778: *15 open socket #17 left in connection 10
2020/11/03 07:00:36 [alert] 70778#70778: aborting
2020/11/03 07:00:36 [warn] 70858#70858: server name "http://safariguides.org" has suspicious symbols in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/kpsga:3
2020/11/03 07:00:36 [warn] 70869#70869: server name "http://safariguides.org" has suspicious symbols in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/kpsga:3
2020/11/03 07:04:34 [warn] 70893#70893: server name "http://safariguides.org" has suspicious symbols in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/kpsga:3
2020/11/03 07:04:34 [warn] 70905#70905: server name "http://safariguides.org" has suspicious symbols in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/kpsga:3
2020/11/03 07:08:24 [error] 70907#70907: *5 open() "/home/sammy/webapps/kpsga/media/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 128.199.240.166, server: http://safariguides.org, request: "GET /media/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml HTTP/1.1", host: "safariguides.org"
2020/11/03 07:08:24 [error] 70907#70907: *7 open() "/home/sammy/webapps/kpsga/media/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 128.199.240.166, server: http://safariguides.org, request: "GET /media/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml HTTP/1.1", host: "safariguides.org"
```

the error for a charachter i suspect is from `http:\\` before sending this I removed it, restarted nginx but still the domain doesn't register.

Comment: `http://safariguides.org`, `162.243.173.84` and `safariguides.org` are all reachable without any problem ! usually 24h are enough for DNS propagation

Comment: @cizario I don't think DNS propagation is the issue more likely domain linking to nginx and django I've waited probably ~23hrs